# Why will Python not let me open up Terminal?

Tags: python, terminal

I want to open Terminal in Python with some simple code and then have it run some commands. However, when I run the commands, nothing happens and Terminal doesn't open.

```
import os
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"python ~/Documents/program.py; exec bash\"'")
```

I got this code from other questions on stackoverflow.com and they keep saying the code is working even though I'm doing the same thing as them, I think at least. Any thoughts? Also, I'm doing this all on macOS Sierra if that helps at all.

Comment: Why are you trying to use Python to run a bash terminal in order to run another python file?

Comment: Why are you blindly trying to run code you don't understand? And you can't run `terminal -e` because `terminal` isn't a command on *nix. If you don't understand what `gnome-terminal` means, then a) you shouldn't be trying to run it, and b) you should learn how to use your OS first before trying to do things in it with a scripting language.

Comment: you mention Terminal, which is a Mac OS Application, so I suspect you are trying to do this on Mac. What OS are you using? Windows 7 or 10? Mac OS X? a Linux distro like Ubuntu, Debian?

Comment: I'm using macOS Sierra

Comment: (Hm, Interesting how supported comments of low-rep users get deleted..by high-rep users :-? ) Anyways, @JosephOdeh, ok I've found one way, but it requires creating a `bash` script that python runs. If you're interested, create a bash script, say, called `open_terminal.sh` and put this answer in it: [Opening a new terminal from the command line and running a command on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/a/308460)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All-in-one python script, without needing a separate `bash` script.

```
import os

os.system("""osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
             do script "python ~/Documents/program.py"
             end tell' """)
```

[image: Open Terminal Sesame!]

Adapted from this answer  [Opening a new terminal from the command line and running a command on Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/a/308460)

Comment: Does it work for you? I think because it's using the underlying [osascript](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html) command native to Mac OS, which I found in that linked answer. We could probably generalize this to use `bash` scripts (like you've done in your question), but I couldn't figure out how to do that yet. Depends if you have specific requirements or constraints, but this was the first working solution I found.

Comment: Yeah, it works great! Thanks! Also, could you upvote my post? I think that rude guy downvoted it and now I may not be able to post again.

Comment: Sure I will, I think you're right, and if this answer works consider accepting it with the little green check mark, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Where are you running this from? Is this from ssh? The program gnome-terminal has to have proper X11 Display to spawn the GUI on. Typically, this would be done by setting DISPLAY=:0.0 such as `export DISPLAY=:0.0`.

`terminal -e` will not work because it is not a command. `gnome-terminal` is a command that can be executed.